# AdvancedFilter CopyToRange:= First empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use AdvancedFilter in VBA, but instead of setting copy to range to a fixed value I want to copy it to the first empty row.

I am trying to append two tables from two separate AdvancedFilter steps, is there an easier way? E.g. first copy the two tables to separate location and then merge them? Both table have the same columns.

My code as of now is:

```
Set rngCriteria_v = Sheets("1").Range("filter")
     Set rngExtract_v = Sheets("2").Range("**Here first empty row**")
     Set rngData_v = Sheets("3").Range("Input")


     rngData_v.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                             CriteriaRange:=rngCriteria_v, _
                             CopyToRange:=Sheets("Stocks_5_control").Columns("AG").Find(vbNullString, Cells(Rows.Count, "AG")), _
                             Unique:=False
```

Comment: So to get this straight, you want to merge two filtered worksheets, in to a new merged worksheet? Or are they in seperate workbooks?

Comment: They are in the same worksheet and workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your advanced filter line to this:

```
rngData_v.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngCriteria_v, Sheets("Stocks_5_control").Cells(Sheets("Stocks_5_control").Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp)(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me: `VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error`   I think its not moving to the first empty row in `AG`

Comment: This should definitely move to the first empty row. But it could be something else. Is there any chance you can send me the workbook? I can sort it out quickly. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: This won't solve the error issue, but I think you need `.Offset(1)` after `(xlUp)` to get to the next empty row. `End(xlUp)` will put you on the last row with data.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I just appeded `(2)` to the answer which amounts to the same. Thanks. And you are right, it won't solve the error. There is something else going on here that it hard to see without the workbook.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman On second thought, it might, because it was probably considering the existing data found on the last row as headers. Please test it again, user3614882.

Comment: @user3614882 My answer has been updated. I think this will work. While it looks substantially the same as before there is one small change. Please try it again and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The following merges the all the worksheets in to a new sheet called Master. Hope that helps :)

```
Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets
 Dim wd As Object 'used for word document
Dim WDoc As Object
Dim strWorkbookName As String
Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
        "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next sht




 'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
 'Rename the new worksheet
trg.Name = "Master"
 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
     'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If
     'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
Next sht
 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit
```